# Best database design to have efficient analysis on it with some millions records

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a basic question about database designing.

I have a lot of files which I have to read and insert them in database. Each file has some thousand lines and each line has about 30 fields (by these types: `small int`, `int`, `big int`, `varchar`, `json`). Of course I use multi threads along with bulk inserting in order to increase insert speed (finally I have 30-40 millions records).

After inserting I want to have some sophisticated analysis and the performance is important to me.

Now I get each line fields and I'm ready to insert so I have 3 approaches:

**1- One big table:**

In this case I can create a big table with 30 columns and stores all of the files fields in that. So there is a table with huge size which I want to have a lot of analysis on it.

**2- A fairly large table (A) and some little tables (B)s**

In this case I can create some little tables which consist of the columns that have fairly identical records if we separate them from the other columns. So these little tables just has some hundred or thousand records instead of 30 millions records. So in fairly large table (A), I emit the columns which I put them in another table and I use a foreign key instead of them. Finally I has a table (A) with 20 columns and 30 millions records and some tables (B) with 2-3 columns and 100-50000 records for each of them. So in order to analysis the table A, I have to use some joins ,for example in select and ...

**3- just a fairly large table**

In this case I can create a fairly large table like table A in above case (with 20 columns) and instead of using foreign keys, I use a mapping between source columns and destination columns (this is something like foreign keys but has a little difference). For example I have 3 columns c1,c2,c3 that in case 2, I put them in another table B and use foreign key to access them, but now I assign a specific number to each distinctive records consist of c1,c2,c3 at inserting time and store the relation between the record and its assigned value in the program codes. So this table is completely like the table A in case number 2 but there is no need to use join in `select` or ...

While the inserting time is important, the analysis time that I will have is more important to me, so I want to know your opinion about which of these case is better and also I will glad to see the other solutions.

Comment: You have missunderstood what database design is and what it does. It's not possible to answer your question because there is nothing inherently wrong in one big table or two big tables or 14 tables with or without referential integrity. It all depends on your requirements and analysis patterns, none of which you have shared.

Comment: The solution is normalisation- combined with appropriate indexes

Comment: @Ronnis you are true, for example if I want to have a select query, which of these solutions is better to use?

Comment: @Strawberry normalization and indexes can be applied to all of these solutions. At the same situation, which of these solutions is better?

Comment: You are asking should I buy a bus, tractor or a sports car. And you are narrowing it down to us by saying things like "it must have wheels, be powerful and move from here to there. They all satisfy those requirements. Your understanding of database design is fundamentally flawed. You have identified problems that don't exist and you have found a few random solutions and now you are asking us which one is the best? I don't want to come off as rude, but you need to understand that you are doing this the wrong way. Read up on *normalization*. Test & evaluate and then ask for advice.

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective 30 to 40 million is not that bad a number. Performance is fully dependent on how you would design your DB to be.

1. If you are using SQL Server then you could consider putting the large table on a separate database file group. I have worked on one case in a similar fashion where we had around 1.8 Billion record in a single table.
2. For the analysis if you are not going to look into the entire data in one shot. You could consider a vertical partitioning of the data. You could use a partition schema based on your need. Some sample could be to split the data as yearly partitions and this will help if your analysis will be limited to a years worth of data(just an example).
3. The major thing would be de-normalization /normalization based on your need and of course non clustered/clustered indexing of the data. Again this will depend on what sort of analysis queries you would be using.

Comment: thanks, I use MySQL. My question is that which of the solution I mentioned is better. At now I don't need to now the methods to increase analysis performance which is another question. I want to know which of these solutions is lead to a better analysis performance.

Answer (score 0):

A single thread can `INSERT` one row at a time and finish 40M rows in a day or two.  With `LOAD DATA`, you can do it in perhaps an hour or less.

But is loading the real question?  For doing grouping, summing, etc, the question is about `SELECT`.  For "analytics", the question is not one of table structure.  Have a single table for the raw data, plus one or more "Summary tables" to make the selects really fast for your typical queries.

Until you give more details about the data, I cannot give more details about a custom solution.

Partitioning (vertical or horizontal) is unlikely to help much in MySQL.  (Again, details needed.)

Normalization shrinks the data, which leads to faster processing.  But, it sounds like the dataset is so small that it will all fit in RAM??  (I assume your #2 is 'normalization'?)

Beware of over-normalization.